# Evaluating $e^{i(i \ln \pi)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have this expression
$$e^{i(i \ln \pi)}$$ and I wanted to know if I could plug the argument into Euler’s formula or if I have to multiply it out.

Comment: Do you mean $e^{i(i\ln\pi)}$?

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr). Please change `e^i(i ln π)` to `$e^{i(i\ln\pi)}$` for $e^{i(i\ln\pi)}$ or `$e^i(i\ln\pi)$` for $e^i(i\ln\pi)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply,

$$e^{i(i\ln \pi)}=e^{-\ln\pi}=\frac1\pi.$$

You *could* plug it into Euler's formula, which will give you $e^{i(i\ln \pi)}=\cos(i\ln\pi)+i\sin(i\ln\pi).$ However, this would be of little use, since [the definition of $\sin$ and $\cos$ for complex arguments involves exponentials.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#In_the_complex_plane)

Comment: But that’s okay. Since $\cos it=\cosh t$ and $\sin it=i \sinh t$, this is just $\cosh\ln\pi -\sinh\ln\pi$ which is $e^{-\ln\pi}=1/\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly plug it in as Euler's formula holds for all complex arguments.

$e^{i(i\ln \pi)} = \cos (i\ln \pi) + i\sin (i\ln \pi) = \cosh (\ln\pi) - \sinh(\ln\pi) = \frac 1{\pi}$

which is exactly the same result you get from simply multiplying the exponent the "usual way" without using Euler's formula.